# CSS 3 Animation - Easing

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have this image that rotates on it's axis using this code:

```
@keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.spinner {
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: 100;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

This works fine, but the problem is I want the animation to start slow, speed up and then take some time slowing down.
If I use **animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;** I get the desired effect but only on each iteration. I would like to apply the timing function to the entire animation (all iterations).

Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Comment: you could change your animation to provide 100 keyframes at 3.6 degree intervals, then setting iteration count to 1

Comment: give us your fiddle link we can update you with solution there

Comment: Multiple keyframes like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NCSaA/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
        80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(700deg); }
      100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg); }
 }
```

It rotates 2 times now and gets slower on 80%.

Comment: perfect, didn't realise you could go over 360deg

Answer (score 0):

You can progressively increase your keyframes, like this:

```
@keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg); }
    60%,100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BW6SX/2/

Comment: this is good, but what happens when I want it to actually rotate past 360deg? I need it to loop a few times but get slower towards the end

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this... notice how the 10% increments are even but the degrees rotation increase giving the effect you desire...

```
@keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); } 
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    90% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }   
    }

.spinner {
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: 100;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: same issue as above, this is great for 1 complete cycle. I need it to rotate completely at least a few times and slow down towards the latter iterations.